# Destroying class instance with db connection

Tags: php

I have a class that looks like this:

```
 class CustomerModel {

     private $db;

     public function __construct (\PDO $db) {

         $this->db = $db;
     }
```

Once I've finshed with the class should I unset it? Would doing an unset destroy the db connection inside too? Or do I need to do that first?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `finshed with the class` really means. But as you just passing `PDO` object to the class, you should NOT close the connection here because it was not created here in first place. But since PHP will cleanup all the stuff when script execution is over or terminated, and your `CustomerModel` most likely does not consume megabytes internally, you may choose to just leave it.